# How to URL encode data in JSON format in Python?

Tags: python, json, encode, urlencode

The code:

```
import urllib.parse

print(urllib.parse.urlencode({"59764":1}))
```

The problem:
The print function should return %7B%2259764%22%3A1%7D but instead returns 59764=1

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're urlencoding a dictionary.

Instead, you should `json.dumps` the dictionary to a string then `quote` it:

```py
import json
import urllib.parse

value_dict = {"59764": 1}
value_str = json.dumps(value_dict)
print(urllib.parse.quote(value_str))
```

Output: %7B%2259764%22%3A%201%7D